# Django - annotate on multiple fields and load relevant objects

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following models

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ...

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    ...
```

For some reason, I want to query books and group results by the author and publisher, so:

```
books = Book.objects.values('author', 'publisher').annotate('sth'=Avg('sth_else'))
```

with the results looking like:

```
<BookQuerySet [{'author': 2, 'publisher': 1, 'sth': 1.0}]>
```

Is it possible to load the whole Author and Publisher objects and not just their related ids?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it isn't. In order to get the respective author and publisher objects. you might have to just use the ids you got here from the query and make another query.

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(id__in = authors)
publishers = Publisher.objects.filter(id__in = publishers)
```

where authors,publishers is the list of ids you got above